# JSX dot notation Components in Clojurescript Reagent

Tags: jsx, clojurescript, reagent, dot-notation

I am trying to use a predefined React component with dot notation as such `MultiSelect.Filterable` in Reagent Clojurescript application but I can't seem to find the correct way to require it.

I am using a namespace `:require` like this, which doesn't work.

```
(ns example-app (:require [carbon-components-react :refer [MultiSelect]])
(def main []
  [:> MultiSelect.Filterable {:id "example"}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that the dot notation is not parsed properly, what works is using the component as such

```
(def main []
  [:> (.-Filterable MultiSelect) {:id "example"}])
```